# Convert a spool into text format

Tags: abap

I want to send the spool generated by a Smart Form, by email as attachment in TXT format.

The issue is to get the spool in a TXT format, without technical stuff, just the characters in the form.

I have used the function module `RSPO_RETURN_SPOOLJOB` for getting it, but it returns a technical format like this:

```
//XHPLJIIID    0700 00000+00000+
IN01ES_CA930_DEMO_3  FIRST
OPINCH12  P 144  240 1728020160000010000100001
IN02MAIN
MT0100808400
CP11000000E
FCCOURIER 120  00144 SF001SF001110000144E
UL +0000000000000
ST0201614Dear Customer,
MT0214209000
ST0864060We would like to take this opportunity to confirm the flight
MT0100809360
ST0763253reservations listed below. Thank you for your custom.
...
```

I want something as follows, without the technical stuff:

```
     Dear Customer,

          We would like to take this opportunity to confirm the flight
     reservations listed below. Thank you for your custom.
     ...
```

This is the code I have used :

```
PARAMETERS spoolnum type TSP01-RQIDENT.
DATA spool_contents type soli_tab.
CALL FUNCTION 'RSPO_RETURN_SPOOLJOB'
  exporting
    rqident = spoolnum
  tables
    buffer  = spool_contents
  exceptions
    others  = 1.
```

Comment: Yes, it is possible.

Comment: This question is also asked in the [SCN forum](https://answers.sap.com/questions/785715/convert-a-spool-in-txt.html) with much more details

Comment: Could you [clarify your question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to indicate which spool type it is among ABAP List, OTF (SAPscript and Smart Form), PDF, RDI, binary, etc. As you use the menu to save as text, the most probable is an ABAP List (ABAP program using WRITE statements) i.e. only a text (usually) with possibly basic colors and styles but no fonts ; extracting the text would mean take the characters as they are, but without colors and styles, and save it to a file on the user's laptop.

Answer (score 0):

If the parameter `DESIRED_TYPE` is not passed or has the value `'OTF'`, and the spool is of type SAPscript/Smart Form, the function module returns the technical format you have experienced.

Instead, you should use the parameter `DESIRED_TYPE = 'RAW'` so that all the technical stuff is interpreted and the form is returned as text, the way you request, as follows :

```
CALL FUNCTION 'RSPO_RETURN_SPOOLJOB'
  exporting
    rqident      = spoolnum
    desired_type = 'RAW'
  tables
    buffer       = spool_contents
  exceptions
    others       = 1.
```